# URL Hash display like url.com/something#/ instead of url.com/something/#/

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-routing

I face to this problem, I using angular v1.6.5 , my route act weird , let's say I have this route :

```
 $routeProvider
        .when('/', { templateUrl: 'myTemplate', controller: 'myController', method: 'myMethod' })
}
```

and my url is like myUrl.com/sectionName what I expect to get is :

```
myUrl.com/sectionName/#/
```

but instead I get this :

```
myUrl.com/sectionName#/
```

I still can get my data and controllers works fine in this route, but cause some other problems ( for instance cannot detect onhashchange event )

I searched for similar problems but most of them was about some other issues like some extra chars ( like '!' ) which can be fixed by using `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');` and I also already used it in my config, but in my case, the problem is something else.

So if any help on this I will appreciate it.

Comment: Can you reproduce same problem in jsfiddle using your sample code? It will be easier then to help u.

Comment: do you have a `<base>` tag in your HTML? Can you try `<base href="sectionName" />` and see if it helps?

Comment: @Claies Yes I do have it and my base is the root <base href="/">

Answer (score 1):

```
    angular.module('myapp', [])
       .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'partials/home.html',
                controller : mainController
            })
       $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <base href="/">
</head>
```

Try this, it will prettify your links.

Comment: Thanks, I try this but the issue is still there.

Comment: wouldn't know exact problem unless you reproduce in jsfiddle.

Comment: well can't reproduce it exactly, this is part of a large .NET MVC base web application, I try to reproduce it in an example with same routes in jsfiddle, but it was fine. thanks anyway.